# Automatically sum of new added Excel Sheet in Total Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook in which I have tabs representing dates along with sum in each tab. Although I can take the sum of all these in the final sheet, I want a formula/macro to get the sum in the total named sheet, when a new spreadsheet is being added.

Note:- the cell in all would remain the same (E56)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what you are attempting.  Until the user has placed information in the new sheet that results in a value in E56, I see little point to adding the value of NewSheet!E56 to the total sheet.

However I suspect you need to use events.  Below are a number of event routines which must be placed in the Microsoft Excel Object `ThisWorkbook` for the workbook.  These just output to the Immediate window so you can see when they are fired.  Note: several can be fired for one user event.  For example, creating a new worksheet, triggers: "Create for new sheet", "Deactivate for old sheet" and "Activate for new sheet".

Do not forget to include

```
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

around any statement within one of these routine that will trigger an event.

Perhaps you need to use SheetDeactivate.  When the users leaves a sheet, check for a value in E56.  If present, check for its inclusion in the totals sheet.  Have a play.  Do what your users do.  Add to these routines to investigate further.  Good luck.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

  Debug.Print "Workbook_SheetActivate " & Sh.Name

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

   Call MsgBox("Workbook_BeforeClose", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)

  Debug.Print "Workbook_SheetChange " & Sh.Name & " " & Source.Address

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

  Debug.Print "Workbook_SheetDeactivate " & Sh.Name

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

  Debug.Print "Workbook_NewSheet " & Sh.Name

End Sub
Sub Workbook_Open()

   Debug.Print "Workbook_Open"

End Sub
```

**Extra section in response to clarification of requirement**

The code below recalculates the grand total of cell E56 for all worksheets except TOTAL and stores the result in worksheet TOTAL every time the workbook is opened and every time the user changes the current worksheet.

It is difficult to get consistent timings with Excel but according to my experimentation you would need between 500 and 1,000 worksheets before the user would notice a delay switching worksheets because of this recalculation.

I am not sure if you know how to install this code so here are brief instructions.  Ask if they are too  brief.

- Open the relevant workbook.
- Click `Alt+F11`. The VBA editor displays. Down the left you should see the Project Explorer. Click `Ctrl+R` if you do not.  The Project Explorer display will look something like:

.

```
VBAProject (Xxxxxxxx.xls)
    Microsoft Excel Objects
       Sheet1 (Xxxxxxxxx)
       Sheet10 (Xxxxxxxxx)
       Sheet11 (Xxxxxxx)
       :
       ThisWorkbook
```

- Click `ThisWorkbook`.  The top right of the screen with turn white.
- Copy the code below into that white area.
- No further action is required.  The macros Workbook_Open() and Workbook_SheetDeactivate() execute automatically when appropriate.

Good luck.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcAndSaveGrandTotal()

  Dim InxWksht As Long
  Dim TotalGrand As Double

  TotalGrand = 0#
  For InxWksht = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Not UCase(Worksheets(InxWksht).Name) = "TOTAL" Then
      ' This worksheet is not the totals worksheet
      If IsNumeric(Worksheets(InxWksht).Range("E56").Value) Then            '###
        TotalGrand = TotalGrand + Worksheets(InxWksht).Range("E56").Value
      End If                                                                '###
    End If
  Next

  'Write grand total to worksheet TOTAL
  ' ##### Change the address of the destination cell as required  
  Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("D6").Value = TotalGrand

End Sub
Sub Workbook_Open()

  ' The workbook has just been opened.

   Call CalcAndSaveGrandTotal

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

  ' The user has selected a new worksheet or has created a new worksheet.

   Call CalcAndSaveGrandTotal

End Sub
```

Comment: My question was that in an excel sheet if i add new sheets every day , i want the sum of each sheet to be calculated automatically in sheet named TOTAL, and E56 is the cell which will contain the sum for every sheet irrespective of the data in that sheet. If the above example represents the same then kindly let me know, and thanks for your generous help in advance, as i don't know how to write macros, but if you'll make me understand i may end up writing it:)

Comment: I do not understand your requirement enough to be more specific at the moment. You may not know VBA but what information do you think a VBA programmer would need to meet your requirement.  Here are some example questions. How is a new worksheet created?  For example, is it being manually created by a user or is it is being imported from a web site?  How many sheets in total?  Once a sheet has been created, does its value change?  Where is the total to be placed within worksheet TOTAL?

Comment: Sheets are created manually everyday.At max 20 sheets per month.Value will not change for the previous date,The Sum in total sheet could be placed anywhere with a heading , like i thought i top be D6..Let me know if you require the sample excel on your personnel email.

Comment: I have added an extra section to my answer.  I hope this provides everything you need.  Ask if it does not.

Comment: i tried your example that you have given above but unfortunately i am not being able to achieve the outcome, as it throws multiple errors, kindly help for the same.

Comment: Saying the code throws mutliple errors does not help identify the cause.  What happens when you open the workbook?  On which line does the macro stop?  What error message is displayed?  However, reviewing my code I realised that it will throw an error if cell E56 is not numeric.  I have amended my routine to correct this.  Please add the two lines ending '### to `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the programming forum, but this particular "need" seems to be solvable without all the plumbing.

I like the old hidden FIRST and LAST sheets trick.

1. Create a sheet called **First**
2. Create a sheet called **Last**
3. Place your current data sheets between these two sheets.
4. Hide the sheets **First** and **Last**
5. Now you can use 3D formulas to sum cells from all these sheets, like so: 
   **=SUM(First:Last!E56)**
6. Now just add sheets to your workbook AFTER the last visible data sheet and Excel will still slip it in ahead of the hidden LAST sheet, so your formula just expands itself that way